# Wrong Olson Timezone Offsets?

Tags: php, timezone, timezone-offset

Today I noticed that my script to convert and display Olson timezone IDs into Cities and GMT offsets was producing some very weird results: Argentina zones caught my attention because they were displaying a standard (non-DST) time offset of ±0000 in reference to GMT/UTC.

I examined my code and I found a small bug in my logic, however it wasn't related to the discrepancy, so I updated `timezonedb` via `pecl` to version `2012.8` but it's still returning the wrong offset...

Here is some code that returns the last 3 changes to the `America/Argentina/San_Luis` timezone:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Argentina/San_Luis');
$transitions = $timezone->getTransitions();

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_slice($transitions, -3, null, true));
echo '</pre>';
```

And this is the output:

```
Array
(
    [59] => Array
        (
            [ts] => 1223784000
            [time] => 2008-10-12T04:00:00+0000
            [offset] => -10800
            [isdst] => 1
            [abbr] => WARST
        )

    [60] => Array
        (
            [ts] => 1236481200
            [time] => 2009-03-08T03:00:00+0000
            [offset] => -14400
            [isdst] => 
            [abbr] => WART
        )

    [61] => Array
        (
            [ts] => 1255233600
            [time] => 2009-10-11T04:00:00+0000
            [offset] => -10800
            [isdst] => 1
            [abbr] => WARST
        )
)
```

As you can see, the indexes `59` and `61` are DST offsets while the index `60` is a standard time offset.

However, if you check [Time&Date](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=613) the standard offset should be `-10800` (3 hours) and not `-14400`:

```
Standard time zone: UTC/GMT -3 hours
No daylight saving time in 2012
Time zone abbreviation: ART - Argentina Time
```

In fact, even the `abbr` is wrong (should be `ART` since on [2009-10-10](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=613&syear=2010) DST was discontinued).

What's going wrong here? I'm pretty sure this is irrelevant but I'm running PHP 5.4.6 if it matters.

**PS**: I remember reading about some legal issues with the Olson database, might this be related?

---

**UPDATE**: I wrote a little script to compare the PHP non-DST offsets with [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones):

```
function getStandardOffset($timezone)
{
    $timezone = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
    //$hemisphere = (ph()->Value($timezone->getLocation(), 'latitude') >= 0) ? 'north' : 'south';
    $transitions = array_reverse(array_slice($timezone->getTransitions(), -3, null, true), true);

    foreach ($transitions as $transition)
    {
        if ($transition['isdst'] == 1)
        {
            continue;
        }

        return sprintf('%+03d:%02u', $transition['offset'] / 3600, abs($transition['offset']) % 3600 / 60);
    }

    return false;
}

$diff = array();
$html = ph()->HTML->DOM(file_get_contents('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones'));
$timezones = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();

foreach ($timezones as $timezone)
{
    $offset = str_replace('−', '-', ph()->HTML->DOM($html, sprintf('//td/a[contains(text(), "%s")]/../..', $timezone), '0.td.4.a'));

    if (strcmp($offset, getStandardOffset($timezone)) !== 0)
    {
        $diff[$timezone] = array
        (
            'php' => getStandardOffset($timezone),
            'wiki' => $offset,
        );
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($diff);
echo '</pre>';
```

The following time zones differ:

```
Array
(
    [America/Argentina/San_Luis] => Array
        (
            [php] => -04:00
            [wiki] => -03:00
        )

    [Antarctica/Casey] => Array
        (
            [php] => +08:00
            [wiki] => +11:00
        )

    [Antarctica/Davis] => Array
        (
            [php] => +07:00
            [wiki] => +05:00
        )
)
```

It's not a huge deal but I'm curious why this happens since I have the latest version of the Olson tzdb.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia's page on the tz database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#2011_lawsuit), the lawsuit was dropped.  Are you using OS-provided PHP packages?  I expect not given the age of the timzeone database.  Some distributions patch PHP to use the OS-provided timezone database instead of the default one provided by PHP.

Comment: @Charles: Yeah, I'm using https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5 but the weird thing is that I just updated the timezonedb pecl package and it shows up on PHP info. Before that it was displaying `system.0` (or something like that) for the timezonedb version.

Comment: the rules for a given Olson timezone name depend on current date (I don't only mean DST transitions, but other changes too) i.e., your php and wiki results might refer to different dates. [I've printed utc offsets for provided timezones on 2012-01-01 using 2012h db. They coincide with the wiki numbers.](https://gist.github.com/b40b41e6b0446cc8e51a/6adb3b9d8a1aa74f4ae1ff4f709b1cefed5c4662#file_show_utcoffset.py)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: My Python is a little rusty but that seems to be flawed as well. `America/Argentina/San_Luis` is returning the same thing as my last transition: `-03:00` ***while*** on DST, but San Luis isn't experiencing DST since 2009-10-10, and `WAR[S]T` shouldn't even exist anymore (should be `ART` instead). Weird...

Comment: Maybe it stuck in summer time? The code prints current time correctly (google agrees) 2:35 (5:35 utc). Another possibility is that America/Argentina/San_Luis is a historic timezone that is not used anymore (so current rules do not apply)

Comment: Indeed, it seems like San Luis now has a permanent summer time to get the same time zone as the rest of the country. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_Americas#Argentina

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: AFAIK, [`America/Argentina/San_Luis` is still in use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Argentina/San_Luis). Don't get me wrong though, timezone *conversion* yields the correct result, the problem is the *transitions*: if you're assembling a timezone drop down selection for your users to chose from it's advisable to get the standard offset, and having correct timezone transitions is critical for that.

Comment: @BoPersson: Yes, but that's a bug. There should be an extra transition: `[61] => Array([ts] => 1255233600, [time] => 2009-10-11T04:00:00+0000, [offset] => -10800, [isdst] => 0, [abbr] => ART)`... I'm gonna try and find where I can report this bug to IANA.

Comment: @Alix Axel: Could you find out more? I can see that data varies on these change-dates across sources, so I'm not entirely sure this all matches. Even wikipedia says for example, that the DST flag might be the [de-facto relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), not the "real" one. Compared with dateandtime.com I even see different dates (http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=613&syear=2000).

Comment: @hakre: Unfortunately, no. I had more important things to worry about in the meantime and I ended up forgetting about this. I'll try to revisit this question today or tomorrow (it's been a long time so I'm not even sure what the exact problem is anymore) and I'll post the update.

Comment: Could this be because of SanLuis, which has this rule in the official IANA DB:

Rule SanLuis 2008 2009 - Mar Sun>=8 0:00 0 -
Rule SanLuis 2007 2009 - Oct Sun>=8 0:00 1:00 S

Answer (score 1):

I'll take your first example here:

```
[60] => Array
    (
        [ts] => 1236481200
        [time] => 2009-03-08T03:00:00+0000
        [offset] => -14400
        [isdst] => 
        [abbr] => WART
    )
```

> However, if you check Time&Date the standard offset should be -10800 (3 hours) and not -14400

From what I've read, this is not true; according to [this article](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/san-luis-new-time-zone.html), around that time (March 3rd 2009) the timezone was changed to UTC-4 when there's no daylight saving and UTC-3 if there is. Though, the mentioned date in the article is March 14/15 and not March 8 ... I'm not sure what has caused that difference.